# decodeURIComponent mangles path

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I post the following to node (simplified example):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/action");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({path:encodeURIComponent("E:\foo\bar.baz")}));
```

node.js code:

```
app.post('/action', function (request, response) {
    var file = request.body['path'];
    console.log(file);
    console.log(decodeURIComponent(file));
});
```

I get the following output:

```
E%3A%0Coo%08ar.baz
E:♀oar.baz
```

How do I correctly decode this?

Comment: Interestingly, if the path is changed to: `E:\\foo\\bar.baz`, then `decodeURIComponent` works correctly.

Comment: Also interesting is that decodeURIComponent("E%3A%0Coo%08ar.baz") works as expected on the node.js REPL.

Comment: That's a fair point, I can see now that this isn't a node.js issue. Can a moderator edit the title and remove "node.js"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encoding [special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings) in your path as the backslash is reserved for escaping:

`\f Form feed`

`\b Backspace`

When encoded these become:

`%0C`

`%08`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Escaping_characters):

> To include a literal backslash inside a string, you must escape the
>   backslash character

`"E:\\foo\\bar.baz"`

Comment: That makes sense, so would the fix be to replace the backslashes with double backslashes, i.e. `E:\\foo\\bar.baz`?

Comment: Or use forward slash `/`. Windows can handle either if that is what you are targetting. I don't believe the encoding is necessary.